# Python venn package: what format should dataset_dict be?

Tags: python, dictionary, venn-diagram, venn

So I have several lists that contain ID numbers, let's suppose them to look like this:

```
list_a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list_b=[1,3,5,7,9]
list_c=[2,4,6,8,10]
list_d=[1,11,2,22,3,33]
```

My task is to visualize these lists as venn diagrams to show intersection of ID numbers. Thus, i decided to use venn package from python, which has following function:

```
venn(dataset_dict, **kwargs)
```

I tried to use it this way:

```
venn(dict({'List A':list_a, 'List B':list_b, 'List C':list_c, 'List D':list_d}))
```

But error below is occuring:

```
TypeError: Only dictionaries of sets are understood
```

I see that the problem is with 'dataset_dict', how can i improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error implies, you are passing data with the wrong type. Your values in the dict passed to `venn()` are of type `list`, not `set`. You could do :

`venn({'List A': set(list_a), ...})`